# C - Assign String array elements to char* variables

Tags: c, arrays, string

I apologize in advance if the wording of my question isn't quite right in describing my problem!

I have a function as follows:

```
void build(char* rules, char** args) {

}
```

In my function I'm trying to extract the elements in args into an exec system call. For example, from main I'm passing the following as my arguments:

```
char* myArgs[] = {"/bin/ls", "-la", "/", NULL};
```

Then in my 'build' function I want to create the following:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "la", "/", NULL);
```

I've tried creating separate variables as follows:

```
char* arg1, arg2, arg3;
```

and then attempted to assign the elements via strcpy(), but it keeps Seg faulting.

```
strcpy(arg1, args[0]);
```

At the end of the day I want to build the execl() command from the passed arguments, but also have it recognize whether there are two, or three arguments in the args array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use execve or something that takes a char* array directly if you have a char* array?

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick response and tip! That worked with: execve(args[0], args, NULL);

Comment: This `execl("/bin/ls", "la", "/", NULL);` should have been `execl("/bin/ls", "la", "/", (char*) NULL);`. From `exec`'s documentation: ["*The list of
       arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are
       variadic functions, this pointer must be cast `(char *) NULL`.*"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)